# Why did I get this error object has no attribute and suddenly it disapeared

Tags: python, oop, pycharm, attributes

I tried for hours to understand why I got always the object has no attribute error, no matter what i did I always got the error. I deleted the code felt like 100 times, renamed the function and renamed it again how it was when I had the error and suddently it is working now, the code is literally the same nothing changed I even looked in the history My IDE is pycharm, Im using python 3.10. I was so frustrated and cant explain it to myself.

```
class data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = requests.get(url="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&type=boolean")
        self.response.raise_for_status()

    def quest_func(self):

        self.data_list =self.response.json()['results']
        return self.data_list
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe you was putting code in one file but you was running different file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is, but if it is to get the attribute "data_list" you need to call the class then specifically call the quest_func method:

```
import requests
class data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = requests.get(url="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&type=boolean")
        self.response.raise_for_status()

    def quest_func(self):

        self.data_list =self.response.json()['results']
        return self.data_list
# called outside of the class, say in a jupyter notebook or script
def main():
    d = data()
    d.quest_func()
```

or you could call quest_func in the init:

```
import requests
class data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = requests.get(url="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&type=boolean")
        self.response.raise_for_status()
        self.quest_func()

    def quest_func(self):

        self.data_list =self.response.json()['results']
```

Only after calling the quest_func will the data_list attribute be created.  Otherwise call the "self.response.json()['results']" in the init function

```
import requests
class data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = requests.get(url="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&type=boolean")
        self.response.raise_for_status()
        self.data_list =self.response.json()['results']
```